# Getting error when loading JSON from GCS

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am trying to load schema and data from GCS as JSON files. I am using command line for this purpose.

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema=gs://1samtest/JSONSample/personsDataSchema.json SSData.persons_data gs://1samtest/JSONSample/personsData.json
```

But I get this error:

> //1SAMTEST/JSONSAMPLE/PERSONSDATASCHEMA.JSON is not a valid value

But when I change all paths to my local machine it works completely file. But don't know why its getting error for json.

If I run like below after creating table in BigQuery it works fine.

```
bq load  --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON SSData.persons_data  "gs://1samtest/JSONSample/personsData.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `schema` flag/param doesn't support URIs for GCS i.e. using `gs://...`

`bq load --help`

> The [destination_table] is the fully-qualified table name of table to
>   create, or append to if the table already exists.
>
> The [source] argument can be a path to a single local file, or a
>   comma-separated list of URIs.
>
> **The [schema] argument should be either the name of a JSON file or a text schema. This schema should be omitted if the table already has one.**

Only the `source` flag/param (i.e. the data) can be used with GCS URIs.

Comment: is there a work around for this or not? I would like to be able to store the metadata and csv data in a storage bucket and upload it to bigquery from there, but it seems that so far I have to have the metadata file locally as json in order to do this.